# Manually trigger event in HammerJS 2.0

Tags: javascript, triggers, hammer.js, manual

I am trying to manually fire the event in HammerJS but as of now I cannot see any progress. Moreover there are links here which takes you HammerJS documentation wiki which is for the version 1.

Can someone tell me how to fire an event manually using HammerJS 2.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how [HammerJS tests](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/blob/10a29097d8c5244f30a0ba4deab82ce75751b445/tests/unit/assets/utils.js) trigger a touch event.

```js
function createTouchEvent (name, x, y, identifier) {
    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('touch' + name, true, true);

    event.touches = event.targetTouches = [{
        clientX: x,
        clientY: y,
        identifier: identifier || 0
    }];

    //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent.changedTouches
    event.changedTouches = [{
        clientX: x,
        clientY: y,
        identifier: identifier || 0
    }];

    return event;
}

function dispatchTouchEvent (el, name, x, y, identifier) {
    var event = createTouchEvent(name, x, y, identifier);
    el.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

you can for example fire a tap:

```js
dispatchTouchEvent(element, 'start', 50, 50);
dispatchTouchEvent(element, 'end', 50, 50);
```

or a pan:

```js
dispatchTouchEvent(element, 'start', 50, 50);
dispatchTouchEvent(element, 'move', 70, 50);
dispatchTouchEvent(element, 'end', 70, 50);
```

Comment: This appears not to work on non-touch devices, so if you develop a unit test on a touch screen computer then and then run it on a non-touch machine the event will never be seen by hammer. At least this is the situation I'm seeing in Chrome. (yet it seems to work OK in PhantomJS)

Comment: @Aardvark Have you tried running the [HammerJS tests](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/tree/master/tests)? They use the same code.

Comment: The issue was that the built-in feature detection of Hammer will create an InputClass what only listen to the supported events of the browser/computer it's running one. If not changed it very well may detect mouse-input only. We specify an input class on Hammer constructor (Hammer.TouchMouseInput) to bypass this feature detection. If I do this during testing Hammer will "see" my simulated touch events on any machine (since the input class TouchMouseInput will listen for them). I suspect Hammer's unit tests bypass or manipulate the feature detection so they can cover all pointer input types too